Spacing and Font Size Issues in LaTeX with TikZ and Math Expressions
I am experiencing some issues with spacing and font size while using LaTeX to render mathematical expressions. Specifically, I am using TikZ and amsmath in my document.

Question 1: Why is there so much space between the U and the fraction line in the term U/2? How can I reduce this space to make the fraction appear more compact?
Question 2: In my diagram, the term U/2  appears in two different sizes. The one in the equation is larger than the one in the TikZ node. How can I ensure that both terms are displayed with the larger size?


My Code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align}
        \frac{U}{2}
    \end{align}
        
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\r{5.3}
        \def\a{27}
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (A) at (\a:\r);
        \draw (O) -- (A) node[above left=3] {$\frac{U}{2}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


My Outcome:


Question 1: this is a bad idea because of letters like g which have an underhang. The underhang would overlap the horizontal bar if you reduced the space, Question 2: add $\displaystyle\frac{U}{2}$ instead of $\frac{U}{2}$

this is nothing to do with tikz or amsmath you can see this with \documentclass{article} \begin{document} \(\frac{U}{2}+\frac{Q}{2}\) \[\frac{U}{2}+\frac{Q}{2}\] \end{document}

@Jasper This nice comment is a nice answer. Please take a minute and write a definitive answer for this question.

Thank you @jlab, let me do that.

Disclosure: I saw this information on a post by @egreg somewhere (not recently).

Question 1:
The reason why you shouldn't try to reduce this vertical spacing is because of letters like p or g which have an underhang. If you were to reduce this vertical spacing, then the underhang would overlap the horizontal bar.
(Alternatively, if you did it for only letters without an underhang, then they wouldn't all have the same baseline.)
Question 2:
The align environment automatically does display math, whereas tikz nodes automatically do inline math. To make them the same, just type \displaystyle inside the inline math in the node.
